# Python: How to remove string from string

Tags: python

I have this snippet of code that looks like this:

```
server_directory = "/Users/storm/server"
def get_directory(self, username):
    home = server_directory + "/" + username
    typic = os.getcwd()
    if typic == server_directory:
        return "/"
    elif typic == home:
        return "~"
    else:
        return typic
```

And every-time I change the directory out of the two nice server directory and home directory of the user, it would look like `/Users/storm/server/svr_user`. How do I make it `/svr_user2` instead of `/Users/storm/server/svr_user`, since I would like to emulate a home directory and a virtual "root" directory?

Comment: As was mentioned in your other question, check out [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you can do a lot with string manipulation, a better way would be using `os.path`:

```
import os

src = '/Users/storm/server/svr_user'
dst = '/svr_user2'

a = '/Users/storm/server/svr_user/x/y/z'
os.path.join(dst, os.path.relpath(a, src))
```

returns

```
'/svr_user2/x/y/z'
```

Answer (score 0):

The not so politically correct alternative of [eumiro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14892877/1974792) would be:

```
import re

src = '/Users/storm/server/svr_user'
dst = '/svr_user2'

a = '/Users/storm/server/svr_user/x/y/z'
re.sub(src, dst, a, 1)
```

Which yields:

```
'/svr_user2/x/y/z'
```

Notice the `1` which means replace once.